# Submitting from table row PHP

Tags: php, html

How to make something like this:

```
<td>
    <a href="test.php?input=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></a>
</td>
```

to act like this:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="action">Show</button>
</form>
```

By other words, when I fill the form-control with some value and press "Show", the desired action performs.
I want to make the same action by pressing the link in the table.

Comment: the first is a GET request, the second a POST. So you'd need to change `test.php` to react on GET the same way as it did on POST. In other words: you cant (without some javascript that catches the onclick event, then does a form submit in the background)

Comment: I feel that the problem is there. In first case the link in browser is something like: …./test.php?input=2161, in the other just: ……../test.php.
But how to make it?

Comment: change test.php to get 'input' from $_GET instead of $_POST

Comment: I have tried. but.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved
Just : if (isset($_GET['input'])){…….}

Jeff thank you for explanation and suggestions.